# Как убрать курсор выделения текста? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Как убрать курсор выделения текста?
Проблема: при наведении на текст, который имеет свойство disableSelection курсор изменяется на вот такой (2 по счету) а нужен 1ый
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В css стиле нужного элемента:

```
cursor: default;
```

Comment: А если во время dragging курсор меняется, то куда cursor: default; прописать?